# .NET Implement IEnumerator with nullable reference types

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerator, nullable-reference-types

Since the [release of C# 8.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8), I've really been enjoying the 'void safety' with [nullable reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#nullable-reference-types). However, while tweaking a library of mine to support the new feature, I stumbled upon a 'problem' to which I really couldn't find an answer anywhere. I've looked at Microsoft's release notes and the .NET source code but no luck.

TL;DR: the question is essentially whether or not an `IEnumerator<T>`'s `Current` property should be declared as a nullable reference type.

Suppose the following implementation of `IEnumerator<T>`:

```
public class WebSocketClientEnumerator<TWebSocketClient> : IEnumerator<TWebSocketClient> where TWebSocketClient : WebSocketClient
{
    private WebSocketRoom<TWebSocketClient> room;
    private int curIndex;
    private TWebSocketClient? curCli;

    public WebSocketClientEnumerator(WebSocketRoom<TWebSocketClient> room)
    {
        this.room = room;
        curIndex = -1;
        curCli = default(TWebSocketClient);
    }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        if (++curIndex >= room.Count)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            curCli = room[curIndex];
        }

        return true;
    }

    public void Reset() { curIndex = -1; }

    void IDisposable.Dispose() { }

    public TWebSocketClient? Current
    {
        get { return curCli; }
    }

    object IEnumerator.Current
    {
        get { return Current; }
    }
}
```

And suppose the following code to consume the enumerator:

```
public class WebSocketRoom<TWebSocketClient> : ICollection<TWebSocketClient> where TWebSocketClient : WebSocketClient
{
    // ...

    public void UseEnumerator()
    {
        var e = new WebSocketClientEnumerator<TWebSocketClient>(this);
        bool hasNext = e.MoveNext();
        if (hasNext)
        {
            WebSocketClient c = e.Current; // <= Warning on this line
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

The code, as it is, will generate a warning because, obviously, the return type of `WebSocketClientEnumerator<TWebSocketClient>.Current` is a nullable reference type.

The `IEnumerator` interface is designed in such a way that one 'should' call the `IEnumerator<T>.MoveNext()` method to know beforehand if the enumerator has a next value, thereby accomplishing some kind of void safety but obviously, to the eyes of the compiler this means nothing, calling the `MoveNext()` method doesn't intrinsically guarantee that the enumerator's `Current` property is not null.

I would like my library to compile without warnings though and the compiler won't let me leave `this.curCli` with a `null` value in the constructor if it is not declared as a nullable reference type and if it is declared nullable then the 'burden' of checking for a null reference is transferred to the client of the library. Granted, enumerators are generally consumed trough `foreach` statements hence it's mostly handeled by the runtime and it's probably not that big of a deal. It is true that semantically speaking, it makes sense for an enumerator's `Current` property to be `null` because there might be no data to enumerate, but I really do see a conflict between the `IEnumerator<T>` interface and the nullable reference type feature. I'm really wondering if there's a way to make the compiler happy while still maintaining the functionality. And also, what are the conventions in some other languages featuring some void safety mechanisms?

I realize this is kind of an open-ended question but I still think it's appropriate for SO. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would definitely suggest it should be declared as the not-null version. The [documentation for `Current`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerator-1.current?view=netframework-4.8) states that the behavior is defined in the cases where `curCli` is actually null. I'd argue that anyone reading `Current` in those cases has a bug in their code, and it would be best to surface that bug via an exception... which is really easy to do:

```cs
public TWebSocketClient Current => curCli ??
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Current should not be used in the current state");
```

You might want to set `curCli` to `null` when you return `false` as well, so that the exception is also raised if code accesses `Current` after exhausting the enumerator.

At that point, I think your code is *better* than the code generated by the compiler for `yield return`, which doesn't throw exceptions.

Comment: Yeah I hadn't thought about raising an error but it actually makes a lot of sense, I'd also argue that reading `Current` after `MoveNext()` returned false is a bug in the client's code. Good call! Ty!